# How to observe the content of static lib in mac OS?

Tags: macos, static, unix-ar

I create a static library project in my xCode and build a *.a named mylib.a.  There some code (*.m files) and another static lib file named common.a to inform the static library nylib.a.
But I doubt that if the contend of common.a are pack in the mylib.a really.
So how can I observe the content of the mylib.a in mac OS? I knew there are some command such as ar, nm to complete this task in Linux. but It does't run in mac OS.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

"`nm`" most certainly does exist on the Mac (in the "`/usr/bin/`" folder).

If you do not see it there, then you probably need to install the "Command Line Tools for Xcode" that you'll find at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action (you'll need an Apple Developer login to get access to this).

"`nm`" will dump all the symbols in a static library file for you. [Here is the manual page for it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html).

Comment: **nm** dumps nothing.  Have you tried it on a .so file in Mac OS?

Comment: Running command "`nm -gU ./my-library.a > my-log.txt`" listed more than enough, thanks!!